# How can I add a browser/web game as a non-Steam game to my library?

Tags: steam, controllers

If you want to create a custom Steam Controller configuration for a game you have to add it to your Steam Controller first, and I want to do so for games such as slither.io, and I also would just like to have them in my library.

I know I can just add a shortcut to my browser that opens that link, but Steam doesn't seem to recognize this, at least with Google Chrome.

Comment: I believe in order for Steam to recognize a link it must be presented as an executable, or .exe. Otherwise, steam will not detect it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add your browser (Firfox / Chrome ...) as a non-Steam game
2. Go to your library, right-click the browser and select Properties

[image: Go to Properties]

3. Add the url as an command line argument:

[image]

If you wan't to change the name of the game or the icon you can do this in the properties panel (Step 2).

If you wan't to open the game in a new window:

- Firefox : -new-window url
- Chome : --new-window url

I've tested it for Chrome an Mozilla Firefox

[image: Non steam game web game]

Hope it helped :)

Comment: I just tested it with Google Chrome, Steam doesn't recognize it as open. Note that I already had Chrome open to begin with, but if I have to close it every time I want to play, it's not worth it.

Comment: in firefox you can add something like `new-window <url>` to open a new tab, in chrome you can add `--new-window` to open a new window :)

Comment: for me it worked even if a have chrome open

Comment: Okay, I've done that, and it successfully opens a new window, but Steam still doesn't recognize it as running. Does this work for you? Does it make your name green and say "playing non-Steam game <name>" on Steam friends?

Comment: yes, but it first sais: playing non-Steam game Google Chrome. You can change the name of the game in the Properties tho. As you can see in the edited answer

Comment: It doesn't say anything for me :(

Edit: plus I can't edit controls obviously

Comment: I think it only sais that, when you have chrome closed and then start it from steam, because else it is confused, because youre already in the game. That is the best you can get out of it :) Just use an browser which is not your standart browser and everythink works perfectly fine

Comment: You can try a batch file to start the browser session. If you use e.g. `start /WAIT foo.exe`, then steam probably will list you in game until the batch file closes. As stated in the comment above, you can name the Library item anything you want so it won't look like "foo.bat".

Comment: Doesn't work for me on mac. Even when chrome is closed. I haven't tested it with firefox yet.